# asp:TextBox with TextMode=Password on Chrome and FireFox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, google-chrome, firefox

I have a form with a gridview on it, in which a textbox is set with TexMode=Password in the footer row.
If on login to the application I choose to save the login and password in the browser (it happens in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE), the entered login and password are displayed in the footer row in the password texbox and one of the other texboxes. 
I've tried to set the AutoCompleteType of the password textbox to Disabled, as suggested in some places, but it changes nothing.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you show a code snippet?

Comment: What are the `id`'s of the inputs?

Comment: The code doesn't have any influence here. Once I remove the TextMode=Password from the textbox, it resolves the problem, but it's not an acceptable solution.

Comment: The Ids are "TextBoxAddUserName" and "TextBoxAddPassword", but even when I changed the first one to "TextBoxAddUse", it still got the login string in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across same issue and to stop the browser functionality to save username and password was not appreciable so, I followed these steps:

1) Simply make a dummy textbox for username and password and set their display as none.

2) And place them before the existing textboxes. In my case the same dummy textboxes were filled.

Comment: Thanks. That apparently did it. For some reason, I had to put the dummy username textbox after the real one, and the dummy password textbox before the real one. It doesn't really matter if it does the job. :-)